# Compilation error: "expected primary-expression before ' '" when trying to specify argument type in a function call

Tags: c++, string, function, variables

When I compile my program, I get the following error message:

```
stringPerm.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
stringPerm.cpp:12: error: expected primary-expression before ‘word’
```

I've tried defining the variables on a separate line before assigning them to the functions, but I end up getting the same error message.

What is the cause, and how can the problem be fixed?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string userInput();
int wordLengthFunction(string word);
int permutation(int wordLength);

int main()
{
    string word = userInput();
    int wordLength = wordLengthFunction(string word);

    cout << word << " has " << permutation(wordLength) << " permutations." << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

string userInput()
{
    string word;

    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    cin >> word;

    return word;
}

int wordLengthFunction(string word)
{
    int wordLength;

    wordLength = word.length();

    return wordLength;
}

int permutation(int wordLength)
{    
    if (wordLength == 1)
    {
        return wordLength;
    }
    else
    {
        return wordLength * permutation(wordLength - 1);
    }    
}
```

Comment: `int wordLength = wordLengthFunction(word);`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need "string" in your call to `wordLengthFunction()`.

`int wordLength = wordLengthFunction(string word);`

should be

`int wordLength = wordLengthFunction(word);`

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
int wordLength = wordLengthFunction(string word);
```

to

```
int wordLength = wordLengthFunction(word);
```

Answer (score 7):

You should not be repeating the `string` part when sending parameters.

```
int wordLength = wordLengthFunction(word); //you do not put string word here.
```