# error: expected primary-expression before ‘slide’

Tags: c++, string

I am learning C++ but stuck now. The program of mine is showing the error

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘slide’
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507607/c-expected-primary-expression-before) but it didn't help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int minSwapsHelper(string slide, int n){
    int noOfGirls;
    for(int i = 0; slide[i]!='\0'; i++){
        if(slide[i] == 'G'){
            noOfGirls++;
        }
    }
    int tempNoOfGirls = noOfGirls, maxNoOfGirls = INT_MIN;
    int noOfGirlsAtEachItr[n]={0};
    if(slide[0] == 'G'){
        noOfGirlsAtEachItr[0] = 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        if(slide[i] == 'G'){
            noOfGirlsAtEachItr[i] = noOfGirlsAtEachItr[i-1] + 1;
        }
        else{
            noOfGirlsAtEachItr[i]= noOfGirlsAtEachItr[i-1];
        }
    }

    for(int i = tempNoOfGirls- 1; i < n; i++){
        if(i == (tempNoOfGirls - 1))
            noOfGirls = noOfGirlsAtEachItr[i];
        else
            noOfGirls = noOfGirlsAtEachItr[i] - noOfGirlsAtEachItr[i - tempNoOfGirls];
        if(maxNoOfGirls < noOfGirls){
            maxNoOfGirls = noOfGirls;
        }
    }

    int noOfBoys = tempNoOfGirls - maxNoOfGirls;
    return noOfBoys;
}
int minSwapsToWin(string slide){
    /*int i = 0;
    while(slide[i] != '\0'){
        i++;
    }
    int lengthOfString = i;*/
    int lengthOfString = slide.length();
    return minSwapsHelper(string slide, lengthOfString);
}
 int main(){
 string slide = "BBGBGBG";
 cout<<minSwapsToWin(slide)<<"\n";
 return 0;
 }
```

The problem that I have the code the solution for is as follows:

> Problem:
>
> In a school, the students were playing a game. Initially
>   everyone is standing in a circular path in the school lawn. The
>   student at index 1 is standing next to student at index n and before
>   the student at index 2. All the girls need to stand together to win
>   the game. The girls had influencial power to influence the boys to
>   swap the positions. Help the Girls decide the minimum number of swaps
>   they have to do so that all of them stand together.
>
> Input:BBGBGBG Output:1 Explanation: we can swap the G at index 3 with
>   B at index 6 to get all B and G together.
>
> Input:BGBGGB Output:1 Explanation: we can swap B at index 3 with G at
>   index 2 to get all B and G together.

Comment: The bug is here: `return minSwapsHelper(string slide, lengthOfString);`

Comment: what is this `return minSwapsHelper(string slide, lengthOfString);` ? Also `\0` ?

Comment: Uhh... `std::string` has a method `length()`. You shouldn't check for `\0`, because strings in C++ don't have to end with null terminator.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `std::string` is guaranteed to have a null terminator in C++11 and beyond.  The real issue there could be embedded nulls and the loop would stop early.

Comment: That's why I have commented out that section @Yksisarvinen

Comment: There are a whole lot of questionable programming practices in your code sample. I'd review it line by line with someone with C++ expertise. For example, you declare a variable length array, which is not C++ standard and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Other examples: `noOfGirlsAtEachItr[i-1]` will have undefined behavior when i = 0.

Comment: You made an error, and your compiler won't let it `slide`. →

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `string` from here:

```
    return minSwapsHelper(string slide, lengthOfString);
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions like this because they don't offer much to future askers. They are better handled with an explanatory comment and a closevote.

Comment: @user4581301 No, do not ever provide a technical answer in a comment. That is not what they are for (and the tooltip on the "add a comment" link specifically states this). They cannot be peer reviewed. Either answer in the answer section or do not answer at all.